# How get text without html tag for a text contained in a known html element

Tags: c#, regex

I need to retrieve contents(string without html tags) inside the html element `<div class='important-contents'>...</div>` from an html string.

Actually I can load all text using the following code.

```
  string htmlString= "<html>...</html>";
  Regex regex = new Regex("\\<[^\\>]*\\>");
  return regex.Replace(htmlString, String.Empty);
```

How do I specify contents inside `important-contents` class element?

Comment: I don't think regex is the best route here, there are html classes from memory that can get contents of the tags...

Comment: Please make sure to read first 20+ answers to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) to construct reasonable RegEx.

Comment: @AustinFrench obviously it is not. But OP should already know that (having good number of HTML and C# questions and answers). So while something like HtmlAgilityPack is definitely good approach, I think this should stay as an exercise in creating regular expressions...

Comment: Thank you men, I have heard of `HtmlAgilityPack` but I wonder if including a library only to get a content inside a div is heavy! And I confirm that my html file is well known and will contain a div with a known class...

Comment: If the only requirement for the content is to be inside some arbitrary HTML tag with the `important-contents` class name, a RegEx is a terrible idea. However, if it's always going to be a `div` like the OP wrote, it shouldn't easy for the correct RegEx to handle. **But** the OP never said he wanted to use a RegEx for it...

Comment: Why not traverse the html script via nodes like one would do with XML.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157258/find-specific-data-in-html-with-htmlelementcollection-and-webbrowser and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match what is inside the DIV tag using this [regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)(%3F%3C%3D%3Cdiv%5Cs%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3Fclass%3D%5B%22%27%5D%3Fimportant-contents%5B%22%27%5D%3F%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F%3E).*%3F(%3F%3D%3C%2Fdiv%3E)&i=%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%27important-contents%27%3E%0D%0A...%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E) that features a non-fixed width look-behind (thanks to .NET regex engine):

```
(?s)(?<=<div\s[^>]*?class=["']?important-contents["']?[^>]*?>).*?(?=</div>)
```

Then, to remove all tags, you can use [this regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3C%2F%3F%5B%5E%3E%5D%2B%3E&i=%3Cspan%3EMy%20%3Ci%3Etext%3C%2Fi%3E%3Cfont%20face%3D%22Verdana%22%3E.%3C%2Ffont%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E) to remove all tags inside the matched DIV contents:

```
</?[^>]+>
```

To remove `<script>` tags that may find their way to the DIV tag, let's introduce another step:

```
(?s)<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>
```

I do not know of a way to match discontinuous texts, so it can only be done in {2,} steps.

**DISCLAIMER**: if you have "malformed" HTML, you can get wierd results, or no match at all.

Sample code:

```
var div_rgx = new Regex(@"(?si)(?<=<div\s[^>]*?class=[""']?important-contents[""']?[^>]*?>).*?(?=</div>)");
var tag_rgx = new Regex(@"</?[^>]+>");
var script_rgx = new Regex(@"(?s)<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>");
var txt = "<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<div class='important-contents'>\r\n<script>function getV(str) { return 0; }</script>\r\n<span>My <i>text</i><font face=\"Verdana\">.</font></span>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
var result = div_rgx.Match(txt);
if (result.Success)
   var final = tag_rgx.Replace(script_rgx.Replace(result.Value, string.Empty), string.Empty).Trim();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: what if the div has a script block inside? 
(And I've seen this type of horrible HTML in my days, it's not just to tackle you, things like this exists all over the internet)

Comment: OK, I added this step to the answer.

Comment: Thank @stribizhev but this shows only contents not in any html tag. for example when `<div class='important-contents'>Hello <b>World</b></div>` it returns `Hello` while it should return `Hello World`. in addition after `if(condition)` there is a `{` when the first line is declaring a variable. I edited your code as following `if (result.Success){  var final =tag_rgx.Replace(script_rgx.Replace(result.Value, string.Empty),string.Empty).Trim();}`

Answer (score 0):

Use "'important-contents'>" as a *Match but do not capture* anchor then consume all text until a `<` is hit such as

```
(?:'important-contents'\>)(?<Content>[^>]+)
```

In the above I have placed all of the contents into a Named Match Capture Group named "Content" for easier extraction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regex is not able to do *get string without html tags* in **general case**, because of HTML grammar is not regular. You have two choices:

1. Use full html parser and work with DOM (answer see here [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) for example)
2. Put on task some tradeoffs, for example
   `<div class='important-contents'>` wouldn't contains inner html tags. In case of tradeoffs solution may be like this:

   ```
   var regex = `"<div class='important-contents'>(?<important>.*)</div>";`
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(htmlString, regex);
   foreach(Match m in matches){
       Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["important"].ToString());
   }
   ```