# How to insert string into input field using C# in WPF Webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I have found lots of info on this issue on Stackoverflow, but looks like I'm still missing something. With the Webbrowser I would like to fill in a string into in input field of a certain webpage. By clicking on a button I wish to put some text in the input field.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and the function:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = (HtmlDocument)webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")["username"].SetAttribute("Value", "someString");
    }
```

The second button handles then the webBbrowser1.Navigate method.

Then I get this error:

*{"Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to class type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface."}*

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs in this line:

```
HtmlDocument doc = (HtmlDocument)webBrowser1.Document;
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466273/how-do-i-cast-a-system-windows-control-webbrowser-document-to-an-mshtml-mshtmldo). `webBrowswer1.Document` in WPF returns `Microsoft.mshtml.HTMLDocuement` so Either add reference to Microsoft.mshtml and then:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = webBrowser1.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    var input = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement element in input)
    {
        if (element.getAttribute("name") == "username")
        {
            element.setAttribute("value", "someString");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    dynamic input = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (dynamic element in input)
    {
        if (element.getAttribute("name") == "username")
        {
            element.setAttribute("value", "someString");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

for more information:

- [How can I get an HtmlElementCollection from a WPF WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972874/how-can-i-get-an-htmlelementcollection-from-a-wpf-webbrowser)
- [Find specific data in html with HtmlElement(Collection) and webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157258/find-specific-data-in-html-with-htmlelementcollection-and-webbrowser)